# Parse array of values - jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

Am calling a webservice from my jQuery to fetch both `Staff` and `Student` details. In my web service I have values for Staff as well as Students, and am returning these as array of strings. While returning values am just serializing these two as

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
public string[] fetchStudentStaff(string sectionId)
{
string student;
string staff;
////
////
student = jsonSerialize.Serialize(studentList);
staff = jsonSerialize.Serialize(staffList);

return new string[] { student, staff };
}
```

here I've a variable called `category` for mentioning whether he is a staff or student. and am receiving this in my jQuery part as,

```
    [
    [
        [
            {
                "Name": "shanish",
                "StudentId": "12",
                "Category": "Student",
                "Mobile": "8147708287",
                "Email": "shanish@gmail.com"
            }
        ]
    ],
    [
        [
            {
                "Name": "shanish",
                "StaffId": "78",
                "Category": "Staff",
                "Mobile": "8147708287",
                "Email": "shanish@gmail.com"
            }
        ]
    ]
]
```

here, I tried using `jQuery.parseJSON(data.d)` to group the result, but it results `null`, I need to categorize the result with `student` and `staff`, here I have one student and one staff, for the case of 5 student and 2 staffs, I need to store students in a separate variable and 2 staffs in a separate variable.

I dunno how to achieve this, can anyone help me here...Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would send a structured message:

```
return jsonSerialize.Serialize(new {students=studentList, staff=staffList});
```

Then on the client:

```
$.ajax({url: urlToFetchStudentStaff, data: sectionId, dataType: 'json',
        success: function(result) {
            // assuming result.d is the JSON result message
            alert(result.d.students.length); // d.students is an array of students
            alert(result.d.staff.length); // d.staff is an array of staff
        });
```

Comment: then how can I categorize in jquery

Comment: can u try alert(result). It will be expected to print the JSON data. Can u able to see it ?

Comment: See my updated answer. If you specify `dataType:json`, jQuery should automatically parse the resulting message as JSON, so you shoudl be able to use it directly.

Comment: @HackedByChinese: thanks dude, I hope ur solution will really help me, I'll give a try and let u know

Comment: @VeeKeyBee: the alert box not displaying the exact result, it displays result as [object],[object].....like this, its enough, I can achieve with this, thanks for ur support